# Making a bordered 2D array (C89)

Tags: arrays, c, c89

I'm trying to make a 2D array that can be a varying size based on user input however with the code I have right now whenever the user inputs the size of the 2D array it does not print a '#' layer at the bottom of the array and the top layer is also wrong. Any suggestions to help me fix this error?

Below is the current code for this function as well as the current output based on the current parameters entered

height = 20
width = 60

any help would be appreciated.

Current output:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/* variables */

int j, i, gameover, score;
int x, y, fruitx, fruity, flag;

/* code */

/* Function to draw a boundary */
void draw(height, width)
{
    /* system("cls"); */
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == width || j == 0
                || j == height) {
                printf("#");
            }
            else {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

This is the current output (Screenshot):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4PoR.png)

Comment: What variables are you using for iteration over `width` respective `height`? Are you using the correct variables in your comparisons?

Comment: Welcome to SO. When talk about a "2D array", do you mean some rectangular graphic using `*`? I am asking because there is no array in your code at all. Neither 1D, nor 2D

Comment: You do not print a bottom line because this condition is wrong: `j == height`. Loop counter `j` will never reach that value but only `height-1` before the inner loop stops

Comment: Besides that, you have tagged with C89. That is a really old and limited version of C you should try to get rid of. There have been C99, C11, C17 released as new standards in those 33 years sind C89.

Comment: i, and j will never reach width and height. Add width -1 and height -1 instead

Comment: Ooops. Missed that... You are also mixing your counters. `i == width` => `i == height-1` and `j == height` => `j == width-1`

Comment: Thank you so much, i == width => i == height-1 and j == height => j == width-1 worked great. One more thing, would you ever recommend creating a box like this (not sure if it is actually an array) dynamically using malloc? If so, how?

Comment: Oh and just to touch on C89, I am aware of the limitations that come with it however I was informed to start on C89 for the time being. Apparently Its good for an absolute beginner like myself.

Comment: "Apparently Its good for an absolute beginner like myself." That is completely nonsense. Obviously you have learned to assume "implicit int" declarations for any function or parameter where type is missing. Don't do that!

Comment: Why would you want to use `malloc`? You are just drawing to the terminal. You do not have any variable holding any data that you might allocate via `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

- `void draw(height, width)` is invalid C though may resolve to "implicit int" in ancient versions of C. Either way you should change to `void draw(int height, int width)`
- `for (i = 0; i < height; i++) { for (j = 0; j < width; j++)` implies a relation between `i` and `height` and between `j` and `width`. Therefore `i == width` doesn't make any sense.
- But `i == height` wouldn't make any sense either, since you loop `i < height`, that is between 0 and `height - 1`.

Most likely you intended something like this instead:

```
if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == (height-1) || j == (width-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop fiddling around with individual bytes (characters).

```
void draw( int height, int width ) {
    int i;

    // top row
    for( i = 0; i < width; i++ )
        putchar( '*' );
    puts("");

    // middle rows
    for( i = 2; i < height; i++ )
        printf( "*%*s\n", width - 1, "*" );

    // bottom row
    for( i = 0; i < width; i++ )
        putchar( '*' );
    puts("");
}
```

Because speed is not a high priority the code can be even smaller

```
void draw( int height, int width ) {
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i <= width; i++ ) putchar( i < width ? '*' : '\n' );
    for( i = 2; i < height; i++ ) printf( "*%*s\n", width - 1, "*" );
    for( i = 0; i <= width; i++ ) putchar( i < width ? '*' : '\n' );
}
```